# Was Voldemort susceptible to the Imperius Curse?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, magical-theory, unforgivable-curse

Could he have devised safeguards against it or been powerful enough to resist the effects? Could the Horcruxes have any bearing on its effect over him?

Answer (score 2):

I think he would be able to resist it and the Horcruxes will have no effect as they are only used to attain immortality.

According to Harry potter wiki,

> Resisting the Imperius Curse is possible, but requires great strength
>   of will and character. The fact that it can be resisted makes it
>   unique amongst the Unforgivable Curses as it is the only curse that
>   has a manner of defence. Harry Potter, Barty Crouch Sr. and Barty
>   Crouch Jr. each learned to resist the curse after being subjected to
>   its effects, though the latter two took quite a long time before
>   building the said resistance, and in Barty Sr.'s case, resistance
>   against Voldemort's powerful curse has seemingly caused mental damage.
>   Resisting the Imperius Curse is similar to Occlumency, which requires
>   a great amount of willpower, though it is unknown if Occlumency would
>   actually work against the curse.

Comment: He seems like a good candidate for being able to resist this, especially since he would hate being able to be controlled, so he may have even practiced against it. though again practice requires that he trust someone else.

Comment: who would dare to try and imperious him in the first place?

Comment: Someone arrogant enough to think they could rule through him.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why Voldemort shouldn't be susceptible to the Imperious Curse. The horcrux wouldn't affect it (nor would they be affected by it), because it's his mind that is affected, and not his soul. Also, there is no mention of any kind of magic (or potions, or anything) that would make one immune to the curse. What they do mention is people who learn to resist and not be controlled (Such as Harry). So, once again, there is no reason Voldemort wouldn't be susceptible by the curse.

That being said, he - being the strong wizard he was - would be one to be able to resist it easily. <strike>Not to mention how ballsy one would have to be to try and curse him.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

#### Voldemort would most likely be strong-willed and magically powerful enough to resist it.

The Imperius Curse can be resisted, and it seems likely that Voldemort has the qualities necessary to be capable of resisting it. His Horcruxes would not help him with this, since Horcruxes only tether the soul to life if the body dies, and no known external safeguards for immunity to being Imperiused exist, but he would not necessarily need external aid to resist it. Resisting the Imperius Curse takes a strong will, which undoubtedly Voldemort has.

> “The Imperius Curse can be fought, and I’ll be teaching you how, but it takes real strength of character, and not everyone’s got it. Better avoid being hit with it if you can. CONSTANT VIGILANCE!’ he barked, and everyone jumped.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 14 (The Unforgivable Curses)*</sup></sub>

If strength in magic is also a factor, Voldemort has that as well - even before he learned he was a wizard, he had a very high level of control over his powers.

> “His powers, as you heard, were surprisingly well-developed for such a young wizard and – most interestingly and ominously of all – he had already discovered that he had some measure of control over them, and begun to use them consciously. And as you saw, they were not the random experiments typical of young wizards: he was already using magic against other people, to frighten, to punish, to control.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 13 (The Secret Riddle)*</sup></sub>

Harry was not that level of skilled in magic, and he was able to somewhat resist the Imperius Curse the very first time it was used on him through the strength of his will, and with practice, became able to throw off the Imperius Curse entirely.

> “And then he heard Mad-Eye Moody’s voice, echoing in some distant chamber of his empty brain: *Jump onto the desk . . . jump onto the desk. . . .* Harry bent his knees obediently, preparing to spring.
>
> *Jump onto the desk. . . .*
>
> Why, though?
>
> Another voice had awoken in the back of his brain. Stupid thing to do, really, said the voice. *Jump onto the desk. . . .*
>
> No, I don’t think I will, thanks, said the other voice, a little more firmly . . . no, I don’t really want to . . .
>
> *Jump! NOW!*
>
> The next thing Harry felt was considerable pain. He had both jumped and tried to prevent himself from jumping — the result was that he’d smashed headlong into the desk, knocking it over, and, by the feeling in his legs, fractured both his kneecaps. 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 15 (Beauxbatons and Durmstrang)*</sup></sub>

If Harry was this able to resist the Imperius Curse at his less-skilled level of magical knowledge, then presumably Voldemort would be able to as well. Additionally, Ron mentioned that they received class reading on resisting the Imperius Curse. So it can be studied and it’s likely something Voldemort would have been interested in learning - he certainly would not want anyone controlling him.

> “And when are we supposed to read up on resisting the Imperius Curse with everything else we’ve got to do?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 15 (Beauxbatons and Durmstrang)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, Voldemort could have known the theory of how to resist the Imperius Curse, and would have the willpower to do it, so presumably he would be able to resist it fairly quickly. It might be possible to Imperius him but it’s highly unlikely that it would work for long before he fought it off.